# ui tests in TFS 2017 fail (Release management)

Tags: coded-ui-tests, release-management

I have a test plan(Contains test cases linked to UI tests. hence automated). To run them, i have linked them to a release definition(Continuous deployment). All tests pass, but not UI.

I understood that it does not have an .exe to run. Hence, i've made sure that necessary files + .exe from project's bin folder gets copied to UI project's bin folder.

But, when I see the output in server while creating release, only, dll of test project was copied not .exe files.

I need help in writing my release definition to run all test plans and deployment. I've used TFS 2017, vsTest(version 2), VS 2017

Comment: There are no EXEs for Coded UI tests, there are only DLLs. Coded UI tests are invoked by Visual Studio or by a test agent calling the DLL. You need to ensure that the build machine has support for Coded UI so it contains the code necessary to invoke the tests.

Comment: What's the result if you manually run the code-ui tests in your  test agent n the deployed server? Could you share your release definition setting? Are you run the agent  interactively?

Comment: The ui tests run manually both in client and server. agent is in interactive mode. However, it didn't run from TFS. So, I replaced the ui test class with a new one, copied the old method and committed. It ran successfully.  My release definition has copy task, vs-Test task to run UI,'Test-plan'.

Comment: @AnjaliIyengar Did you mean the issue have been solved  after you replaced the ui test class?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT yes. I assumed it might be due to deletion of some UI configurations. I have no idea how any code or configurations were deleted or misplaced.